# Using Dependency Injection in Aws Lambda, Dotnet core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda

I am new to Aws Lambda. Trying to figure out how to use Dependency Injection in .NET Core 2.1 and Aws Lambda. Here is the function I have:

```
public class Function
{
    ILogger _logger;
    IClient _client;

    public Function(ILogger logger, IClient client)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _client = client;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A simple function that takes a string and does a ToUpper
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var response = await _client.Test();
        _logger.Log(response);
    }
}
```

Where in the Aws Lambda life-cycle can I setup Dependency Injection -- initialize the ServiceCollection and build a service provider?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing that as part of the constructor or at least in a function called from the constructor. That will only be called once per Lambda compute environment versus the FunctionHandler method which is called for every Lambda invocation.

So in the constructor setup the service provider, set it as a member variable and then you will have access to it for all Lambda invocations.